# How to track/debug IE 7 & 6 javascript errors in dreamweaver CS3?

Tags: javascript, dreamweaver

How to track/debug IE 7 & 6 javascript errors in pages in dreamweaver CS3 ? I know how to debug in Visual studio but is it possible in Dreamweaver CS3 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dreamweaver CS3 and CS4 for that matter, do no include a debugger that allows you to set breakpoints and track variable values. You're best off using another tool for the debugging, either move over to Visual Studio to debug a particular page. I've not used Visual Studio for web page debugging, so not quite sure how it works, but if you set Visual Studio as the External Editor in Dreamweaver, you should be able to open the current document in Visual Studio and then use it's debugging tools. To set an external editor in Dreamweaver read the Adobe TechNote: [Setting the external code editor within Dreamweaver](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/152/tn_15238.html), or the Dreamweaver CS4 help docs for [Using an external editor](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/Dreamweaver/10.0_Using/WSc78c5058ca073340dcda9110b1f693f21-7b4aa.html). If you don't have Visual Studio, then perhaps debuggin in Visual Web Developer Express might be useful. Set it as the external editor and then try the steps in [How to debug JavaScript with Visual Web Developer Express](http://www.berniecode.com/blog/2007/03/08/how-to-debug-javascript-with-visual-web-developer-express/) (assuming the steps are correct, haven't tried it).

Then with the document open, go to Edit -> Open with {external editor name}.

Or you can do the debugging from within Internet Explorer. I haven't tried it, but a quick search yields [HOW-TO: Debug JavaScript in Internet Explorer](http://www.jonathanboutelle.com/mt/archives/2006/01/howto_debug_jav.html). I'm sure that there are IE plugins that help or facilitate debugging in Explorer out there.

(Please add references here if anyone is aware of them)